# Parse a multilevel array to view-file

Tags: php, model-view-controller, multidimensional-array, html-parsing

I need to parse a multilevel array to my view file.

My array could be like this:

```
$test = array(
    1 => array(
        10 => array('text' => 'test'),
        15 => array( 
            12 => array('text' => 'Test')
        ),
        'text' => 'Nr. 1'
    ),
    4 => array(
        14 => array('text' => 'Hello'),
        'text' => 'Nr. 4'
    )
)
```

This will be passed to a view file, that could look like this:

```
{test}
    {text}
{/test}
```

My problem is, that this will only show the first level - I want to have unlimited levels.. Is that possible without making a workaround, where I create the HTML in the PHP-file and then passes the HTML to the view file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need a bit of recursion.

```
function recurse_output($input, $level = 0) {
    foreach($input as $key => $value) {
        echo "\n", str_repeat(" ", $level);
        echo "<div>{$key} is: ";
        if(is_array($value))
            recurse_output($value, $level + 1);
        else
            echo $value;
        echo str_repeat(" ", $level);
        echo "</div>\n";
    }
}
```

When run against your input, the result is:

```
<div>1 is: 
 <div>10 is: 
  <div>text is: test  </div>
 </div>

 <div>15 is: 
  <div>12 is: 
   <div>text is: Test   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div>text is: Nr. 1 </div>
</div>

<div>4 is: 
 <div>14 is: 
  <div>text is: Hello  </div>
 </div>

 <div>text is: Nr. 4 </div>
</div>
```

It should be pretty simple to modify the code to not emit anything unless `$key` is `'text'`.  I don't know what template system you've selected for your view mechanism, but *most* of them permit similar recursive calling.

Comment: Well, I use something similar to CodeIgniter... Where would you put the recurse-function?

Comment: The function could actually just be a (partial) template file, really.  I don't know much about CI, but if you can set variables in the context of a template only and it permits templates to include other templates, then you should totally be able to make it recursive.

Comment: Maybe this means I should take my framework up to revision. It is not CI, but I have made my own, where I have had inspiration from the CodeIgniter Template parser.

How could a way of including templates in other templates be made?